# I get and error after upgrading to Xcode 13 and renounce the Legacy build system

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode13

I get the error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" on the RealmJs library when I try to run the app on Xcode 13.
I think it's from the new build system but the Legacy build system is deprecated so I can't go back to it.
Any suggestions?

Environment:
React Native v 0.66
Xcode 13.2.1

Comment: Selected xcframework slice ios-arm64_armv7
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/"
building file list ... done
librealm-js-ios.a
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/38cf1d983f/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/rsync.c(244) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify; [edit] your question instead, so that all information is in one place. Also, code is unreadable in questions. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Open project directory on the terminal and run this command and archive again

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. The error persists